# Change href on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, debugging, internet-explorer-9

I want to change the value "href" in my html page if someone opens it using IE. 
At first I tried with the button, but the final goal is without it.

This is what I have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var oldHTML = document.getElementById('troca').href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/39640718?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0"
var newHTML = document.getElementById('troca').href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VwjI7ICgcJ0?rel=0";
if (navigator.appName!='Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
  **//what action i have to put in here?**
  }
document.getElementById("troca").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p>clique, se for internet explorer nao vai trocar nada!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Troca</button>

<br/><br/>

<iframe id="troca" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/39640718?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="910" height="512" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>

</body>
```

Does someone know what I have to put in there for my code changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://davidwalsh.name/ie-conditional-comments) if you don't want to use JS:

```
<!--[if IE]> hello ie user! <![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
hello non-ie user!
<![endif]>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXZYL/2/) and [another link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/cc2.shtml) about IE conditional comment syntax.

Comment: no problem :) if this answer solved your problem, don't forget to click the check mark next to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `document.getElementById('troca').src=` again with the new value. Just know that browsers can and do lie about their appName. IE tends to be Microsoft Internet Explorer, but just about everything else identifies as Netscape.

`iframe`s do not have a `href`, only a `src`.